# "Grudge" vs. "begrudge"

Tags: differences, verbs, prefixes

In Faulkner's *The sound and the fury* two sentences arrive close to one another which have made me wonder about the usage of grudge and begrudge.

> I know you grudge what I give him.

And shortly thereafter,

> I know you begrudge him.

Now I wonder if the subtle difference of a person or action implies the need for different words.

In essence, I am wondering about the correct usage of these two words in comparison with one another.

Comment: I'm bad at tagging, feel free to improve my tags.

Comment: Just trying something on for size! http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/editing-question-titles-in-pursuit-of-standardisation

Comment: @FumbleFingers I prefer and... I don't really understand the desire to edit this. Based on the meta question it doesn't seem like the community formed a consensus that these changes should be made. :/

Comment: reverted. didn't mean to be rude.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No problem at all.

Comment: *Grudge* can be used both as a noun and a verb, while *begrudge* is only a verb.

Answer (score 3):

> For **begrudge** there are two meanings:

The first one says it's a *trivalent* verb. The [valency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29) in Linguistics indicates how many arguments can be controlled by a given verb.

1. For this first meaning, this verb, in order to work properly needs 3 things: Subject, Direct Object, Indirect Object:
   **Envy** (someone) **the possession or enjoyment of** (something):
   `Example`: *she`(S)` begrudged Martin`(D.O.)` his affluence`(I.O)`.*
2. For the second meaning, it's a transitive verb (Transitive verbs are usually divalent, i.e. two arguments, Subject and Direct Object):
   **Give reluctantly or resentfully**: *nobody begrudges a single penny spent on health.*

---

> For **grudge** I found two meanings as well:

1. **Be resentfully unwilling to give, grant, or allow** (something): *he grudged the work and time that the meeting involved.*
2. Here it's trivalent again:
   **Feel resentful that** (someone) **has achieved** (something): *I don't grudge him his moment of triumph.*

Examples and definitions are taken from the NOAD.

Answer (score 1):

**[Grudge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grudge)** *(verb)* seems to have one meaning, which is focused on giving or conceding:

> to be unwilling to give or admit : give or allow reluctantly or resentfully

While **[begrudge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/begrudge)** has two:

> 1. to give or concede reluctantly or with displeasure
> 2. to look upon with disapproval

The first meaning is similar to the verb *grudge* while the second, which is the meaning used in your quote for *begrudge*, is not shared.

Therefore, while either could have been used in the first sentence:

> I know you [grudge|begrudge] what I give him.

Only *begrudge* fits in the second sentence (to apply disapproval generally).

Comment: I did not recognise the second meaning, and the OED lists it as "obs(olete) rare", and gives one example from 1690. I would read Faulkner's use as a rather questionable elliptical form, with an implied object.